# Add rgba background to multiple different images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, rgba

I am trying to add rgba background to multiple different images. I am using Bootstrap and I am trying to make it responsive. But it looks like something went wrong.

This is an example I am trying to make something like this:

[image]

My code here (HTML):

```css
.text-caption {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.caption:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="text-center">
      <h3>This is some text</h3>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/ffb3d1/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/c2f0c2/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/cc99ff/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: @Pete I would like to make the rgba background separate on each individual image

Comment: @Pete Try to look at the example that included on my question

Comment: See update to my answer

Comment: @Pete Thanks a lot! I will mark it as accepted answer. By the way, can i learn how to make the content wider? Like make the <h3> and <p> wider a little bit. Because it looks like the too narrow for the content.

Comment: Hi Ace the content is as wide as the 3 columns - I gave it col-md12 so it would go across the top of all the other columns.  If you right click and inspect the element in desktop view, you should see it spans all 3 columns.  If you need it wider, you can put it above the container and remove that class but at the moment, the width is only limited by the container

Comment: I just edited the answer as I forgot to copy the col-md-12 from the bootply to the snippet

Comment: @Pete  Got it! Thank you for teaching me so much.

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add z-index's to the absolute positioned elements and relative positioning to the caption to make your code work properly:

```css
.text-caption {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:2;
}

.caption {
  position:relative;
}

.caption:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h3>This is some text</h3>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/ffb3d1/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/c2f0c2/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/cc99ff/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Example Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/V4JNl511pD)

Answer (score 1):

A few things to notice:

- The images chosen are huge and to make it look they fit the container they're in, `overflow: hidden` is included for caption.
- I have limited the height of the caption to 500px. This allows for automatic scaling of the image.

```css
.text-caption {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.caption {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption>img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3>This is some text</h3>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/ffb3d1/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/c2f0c2/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="caption">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/4000x3000/cc99ff/000">
        <div class="text-caption">
          <h3>This is some text</h3>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```